# What is the outcome of mov on non bracket memory locations?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel

I am having problems distinguishing whether the address is loaded or the content from the address. Please help me clarify.

```
1. mov     [rsp+78h+arg_0], rsi
2. mov     rsi, cs:qword_1F39B60
3. mov     [rsp+78h+arg_38], rsi
```

1. If line 2 is loading `1F39B60` in `rsi` or the contents of `1F39B60` in `rsi`?
2. Would `lea rsi, [qword_1F39B60]` be the same?
3. If non bracket using `mov` action on a memory even allowed or this is just a visual IDA thing?
4. Can you explain to me why it shows `cs:` even though `qword_1F39B60` is in the `.data segment`? Shouldn't it be `ds:`?

Last but not the least this isn't directly connected to my main question but is `rsp+78h` a fancy way of saying `rbp` by the disassembler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `rsi` is being copied into `arg_0`
2. `lea rsi, [qword_1F39B60]` means `rsi` would contain a pointer to `qword_1F39B60`
3. Yes it is allowed, it's a mem->reg operation.
4. I believe that `ds` and `ss` are usually set to zero when using 64bit mode, but `cs` is set to the start of the text segment, so is the only segment register that can be used to generate a valid address. (There are some conflicting views on this, and I may be wrong)
5. Usually `rbp` will be set to `rsp` before space is allocated on the stack:

```
push rbp              ; save the current frame pointer
mov rbp, rsp          ; create a new frame
sub rsp, rax          ; allocate space on the stack
```

However, it looks like this program is optimised (omit frame pointers) and is using `rsp` for all references, so `rbp` may be used for anything in this case but not its usual job.